# QuerySet order_by intermediate models

Tags: django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield, django-intermediate-table

I'm trying to create a intermediate model with the `created` field recording the time of following relationship.

The models is as following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='真實姓名', blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='暱稱/顯示名稱')

## the intermediate model is connected through following field  ##
    followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='FollowShip',
                                        related_name='followers', symmetrical=False,
                                        through_fields=('profile_from', 'profile_to'))

    total_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile of User:{}'.format(self.user.username)


class FollowShip(models.Model):
    profile_from = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='follow_from_set')
    profile_to = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='follow_to_set')
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} follows {}".format(self.profile_from, self.profile_to)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile_from', 'profile_to')
```

It works fine. However, when I tried to access the QuerySet order by `created` field of `FollowShip` model. The error occurs.

In `manage.py shell`:

```
>>> user.profile.followings.order_by('followship__created')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 824, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 369, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 47, in pre_sql_setup
    order_by = self.get_order_by()
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 293, in get_order_by
    field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 553, in find_ordering_name
    field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 586, in _setup_joins
    pieces, opts, alias)
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1402, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/Users/young/Desktop/env/strayvoice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1327, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'followship' into field. Choices are: follow_from_set, follow_to_set, followers, followings, id, nickname, realname, total_followers, user, user_id
```

It looks like the intermediate model was not set correctly. So that I cannot find `followship` while query.
However, I can access both sides well.
For examples:

```
>>> user.profile.followings.all()
`<QuerySet [<Profile: Profile of User:222222>, <Profile: Profile of User:333333>]>`
>>> user.profile.followers.all()
`<QuerySet [<Profile: Profile of User:222222>]>`
```

Have no clues what's go wrong.

Comment: The same error message. It looks like the m2m relationship point to 'self' with intermediate model acting different from pointing to different model.

Answer (score 1):

Use `p.follow_from_set.order_by('created')`.

`user.profile.followings` means the profile who the `user.profile` has followed.
`user.profile.followers` means the profile who have followed the `user.profile`.
So both the `user.profile.followers` and `user.profile.followings` will return a queryset of `Profile`, they can only be ordered by the fields of `Profile`, such as user, realname, nickname.

If you want to find the profile which has been followed by `use.profile` and order_by `created`, you can use:

```
result = []
for profile_id in user.profile.follow_from_set.order_by('created').values('profile_to'):
    result.append(Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id))
```

If there are many following, maybe you can optimize the sql by this:

```
profile_ids = user.profile.follow_from_set.order_by('created').values('profile_to')
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(id__in=profile_ids)
```

FInally, reorder the profiles with the order of profile_ids.

```
result = []
result_dict = {}
for profile in profiles:
    result_dict[profile.id] = profile
for id in profile_ids:
    result.append(result_dict[id])
return result
```

Maybe there is many better way to solve the problem. Can any one make a better resolution?

Comment: See the last part of [django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). I supposed I can query like `>>> Person.objects.filter(
...     group__name='The Beatles',
...     membership__date_joined__gt=date(1961,1,1))` as the document said.

Comment: Your way works. But to do so, I must add the hits to database several times, the cost is huge.

Comment: The queryset `Profile.objects.filter(followers__nickname__contains='')` is like what you recommended. Here you may want something like `Profile.objects.filter(follower_from_set__created__lt=datetime.date(2016,1,1))` or `Profile.objects.filter(followers__created__lt=datetime.date(2016,1,1))`(neither of the two worked)

Comment: It seems the only way to access the intermediary model is like what you said through `follow_from_set` or `follow_to_set`.

Comment: Using the second way, it is acceptable. The sql is `'SELECT "myuser_followship"."profile_to_id" FROM "myuser_followship" WHERE "myuser_followship"."profile_from_id" = 1 ORDER BY "myuser_followship"."created" ASC LIMIT 21'` and `'SELECT "myuser_profile"."id", "myuser_profile"."user_id", "myuser_profile"."realname", "myuser_profile"."nickname", "myuser_profile"."total_followers" FROM "myuser_profile" WHERE "myuser_profile"."id" IN (SELECT U0."profile_to_id" FROM "myuser_followship" U0 WHERE U0."profile_from_id" = 1) LIMIT 21'`. I'm little confused what the `LIMIT 21` stand for.

Comment: So i can order profile which user is following by `created` field this way: `user.profile.followings.order_by('follow_from_set__created')`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. The sql shows like this: `SELECT "myuser_profile"."id", "myuser_profile"."user_id", "myuser_profile"."realname", "myuser_profile"."nickname", "myuser_profile"."total_followers" FROM "myuser_profile" INNER JOIN "myuser_followship" ON ("myuser_profile"."id" = "myuser_followship"."profile_to_id") WHERE "myuser_followship"."profile_from_id" = 2 ORDER BY "myuser_followship"."created" ASC LIMIT 21`